# Read txt File with C

Tags: c, file, scanf

After creating a file and writing to it, I now want to try to read the file and put the "content" into a char array (as there are no strings in c).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <time.h>


/*FILE LOOKS LIKE
 /Users/xxx/Desktop/file.txt

 test
 */

int main()
{
    FILE *fr;
    fr = fopen("/Users/xxx/Desktop/file.txt","a+");
    char line[80];
    while(fgets(line, 80, fr) != NULL)
    {
        sscanf (line, "%s");
        printf ("%s \n",line);
    }


    fclose(fr);
}
/* should print "test" */
```

The `.txt` file contains at the moment just 1 line with the text: "test".

Comment: Your sscanf has no matching target parameter for %s and that will likely cause immediate crash.

Comment: Well i thought i need the sscanf (really starter at c), and the problem is i don't get the output in the console

Comment: Adding code without knowing what it does or why it is there is dangerous in C... If you get *lucky*, your program will just segfault immediately.

Comment: [`fscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/) can be used to read files. Obviously you have to use `printf` if you want any output to the terminal. If you have any questions as to what different functions do, you can look at [C++ Reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/) or other pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading the file, not appending to it, then change

```
fr = fopen("/Users/xxx/Desktop/file.txt","a+");
```

to

```
fr = fopen("/Users/xxx/Desktop/file.txt","r");
```